# Make [sitemaps] a synonym of [sitemap]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

The tag [sitemaps](/questions/tagged/sitemaps) has 36 tagged questions compared to [sitemap](/questions/tagged/sitemap)'s 658 questions. They refer to the same thing so they should be merged.

---

### Bumpidty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, a bounty should be placed on a question in order to gain attention to it.  Edits for the purpose of bumping a question are discouraged.

I have to say this as it worked, and the synonym is created.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the advice.